# How to store username and password in autofill programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, security, autofill

In iOS 12 apple have supported autofill option for username and password. But i have not find any programmatic way to save new username and password  to autofill for future use.

How to save to do this in iOS ? is that even possible on iOS for now ?

Answer (score 2):

Store your password to keychain in order to secure them. Here is a good [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/adding_a_password_to_the_keychain) about that.

And here is a videos about autofill from WWDC: [video1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/206/) and [video2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204/?time=33)

Comment: after that password and username will be reflected in autofill ?